# Сравнить и объединить два .txt файла

Tags: php, сравнение

Есть два .txt файла, в каждом по 3000 строк, следующего содержания:

```
E0040150570A27AB
E004015032259B82
E0040150570A27AF
E0040150622F6C00
```

Значения (не строки) в этих файлах могут совпадать.

Как можно эффективно объединить эти файлы в один, где нет повторения в значениях? Пытался выполнить перебор всех записей во втором файле для каждой записи из первого файла, но это медленно и неэффективно.

Спасибо.

Comment: Импорт в Эксель на один лист одно под другим, удаление дубликатов, экспорт в текст - устроит?

Comment: И в чем же у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: @Akina при чем тут excel?

Comment: @Alex78191 Как при чём? предложенная методика решает задачу? решает. А ограничений на используемый инструмент нет.

Comment: @Akina ваш вариант​ похож на использование экселя ради экселя.

Comment: Спасибо всем кто откликнулся!

Comment: @Akina указан тег php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читаете первый файл и создаете массив в котором ключами будут значения строк.

Потом читаете второй файл и таким же образом добавляете в этот массив.

```
$out = [];

$handle1 = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($handle1)) !== false) {
    $out[$line] = true;
}

fclose($handle1);

$handle2 = fopen("inputfile2.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($handle2)) !== false) {
    $out[$line] = true;
}

fclose($handle2);

$result = array_keys($out);
```

Comment: rjhdby, ,большое спасибо, ваш вариант подходит!

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужен PHP для этого.

```
$ cat 1.txt 
E0040150570A27AB
E004015032259B82
E0040150570A27AF
E0040150622F6C00

$ cat 2.txt 
E0040150570A27AB
E004015032259B44
E0040150570A27AF
E0040150622F6C11

$ sort 1.txt 2.txt | uniq
E004015032259B44
E004015032259B82
E0040150570A27AB
E0040150570A27AF
E0040150622F6C00
E0040150622F6C11
```